# What is wrong with my code for validating a BST with BFS level order traversal

Tags: javascript, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, breadth-first-search

I've been trying to get the test cases on OJ Leetcode to pass for validating a BST using level order traversal and it's not passing. I'm passing 73/74 and can't figure out why. Any advice to point me in the correct direction is much appreciated.

Input:      {3,#,30,10,#,#,15,#,45}

Output:     true

Expected:   false

Based on the input, maybe I'm wrong here and please correct me if I am, but I believe the BST should look like the following based on the input:

```
                3
               / \
              N  30
                /  \
               10   N
              /  \
             N   15
                /  \
               N   45
```

Here is my code:

```
var isValidBST = function(root) {
    if (!root || !root.left && !root.right) {
        return true;
    }
    var i = 0;
    var j = -1;
    var queue = {};
    var isValid = true;
    var recurse = function (node, side) {
      if (!node) { return; }
      if (node.left) {
          queue[i++] = node.left;
          if (node.val <= node.left.val) {
              isValid = false;
          }
      }
      if (node.right) {
          queue[i++] = node.right;
          if (node.val > node.right.val) {
              isValid = false;
          }
      }
      if (side === 'left') {
          if (node.val >= root.val) {
              isValid = false;
          }
      } else {
          if (node.val <= root.val) {
              isValid = false;
          }
      }
      recurse(queue[++j], side);
  };

  recurse(root.left, 'left');
  j = j > 0 ? i - 1 : -1;
  recurse(root.right, 'right');
  return isValid;
};
```

Comment: The BST given is invalid.  45 cannot be in the left subtree of 30.